# An elisp function which checks whether the test-string match the regular expression?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a function like (function-name regular-expression-string test-string) in elisp which checks whether the test-string and the regular-expresion-string match?

In my case, I need to use a regular expression to check whether the filename-string is a PDF filename-string.

For example,"/mnt/ntfs/dianzishu/pplib/plan/The_linux_virtual_memory_manager.pdf"

Update: I got it. string-match

Comment: Rather post your solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is string-match.

(string-match "\.pdf\'" file-name-string)